# MySQL - Best practice for retrieving rows with count of details

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

1. master table "writers"
2. details table "books"

Each writer has a list of books she wrote. I want to get all the writers with the number of books each of them wrote.
Is there a way to do it in one query?

Comment: I'm not a fan of these 'do it all for me' questions that masquerade as 'best practice'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe this will work for you. Not sure if there is a more effective way:

```
select id, (select count(*) from books where books.writer_id = writers.id ) count from writers
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the following non-nested version:

```
SELECT
    writers.id, 
    writers.name,
    count(books.*) as BookCount
FROM
    writers
    LEFT JOIN books ON writers.id = books.writer_id
GROUP BY
    writers.id,
    writers.name
```

Comment: This is nice, but it fails if the writer doesn't have any books. I won't get the writer records with BookCount=0

Comment: I will change it to left join. That will give you that. You didn't specify this. A simple change.

Comment: Sorry again, this results in BookCount=1 when there are no books (It joins with nulls)

Comment: Sorry @Mr.Messy, I wrote this half asleep. 3:30 AM Christmas morning. I have changed it.  It should work now.

Comment: It says there's a syntax error on "count(books.*)" (except for the missing comma). Merry Christmas.